# define constant int/char* in .cpp

Tags: c++, static, constants

My project use a `version.h` to configure the app version, lots of source files include this `version.h`, currently it defines the app version like:

```
#define VERSION 1
```

Every time I upgrade to a new version, I need to modify this `VERSION`, and because it's included by all the source files, the whole project recompiles, which takes a very long time.

So I want to split it into **.h** and **.cpp**.  Then I just modify the **.cpp** when I update, and it only recompiles one file.

Here's what I tried:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const static int VERSION;

// some other source code that uses the version
struct traits {
    const static int ver = VERSION; 
};

int main() {
    cout << traits::ver << endl; 

}
```

**version.cpp**

```
const int VERSION = 1;
```

Please note that I need to use it as **static**. But it doesn't compile, error:

> error C2734: 'VERSION': 'const' object must be initialized if not
>   'extern'
>
> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a
>   non-constant symbol
>
> note: see usage of 'VERSION'

What's the best way to define the version code?

Environment: Visual Studio 2015 update 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: The dupe is what you are trying to do. In C++17 there is [inline variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). You should always include error messages.

Comment: This question shows exact way how habit of have compile time constant uppercase created and why it is bad habit.

Comment: "Please note that I need to use it as static" no you do not.

Comment: You could make `version` a function and then auto-generate the cpp file (in your build system of choice) with the function just returning a constant. Then when the version changes, the header stays the same, only the cpp file changes.

Comment: @aj3423 feel free to accept an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**version.h**

```
extern const int VERSION;
```

**version.cpp**

```
#include "version.h"

extern const int VERSION = 1;
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "version.h"

struct traits {
    const static int ver;
};
const int traits::ver = VERSION;
```

[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/toEpPeG9f1YyTpV4)

Comment: `version.cpp` should do a `#include "version.h"` as well.

Comment: `VERSION` should probably be `const`.

Comment: @MarkRansom why? even if its only contain the extern?

Comment: To make sure the definition and declaration are compatible. It's not strictly necessary, just good practice. Would have caught the issue noted by @Jarod42.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something similar.

My **version.cpp** looks like:

```
const int SoftwareVersion = 0xAA55A55A;
```

To Use the Version Number (as example in main.cpp) it looks like:

```
...
extern const int SoftwareVersion;
...
int main(int argc, char **args) {
  printf("Version %i\n",SoftwareVersion);
}
```